# How to read latin caracters (Python)?

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, string, pydroid

I am learning to write code in Python.
I've décided to write a program to increase smbs typing speed. That's why I've found several text documents to select random words from.
I have a problem while reading the french file. It replaces 'é' caracters by '+AOK-'.
I've searched for solutions for that issue, they said it was encryption problem.
I've tried to change file encryption and to read as 'latin-1', but that did not work.
I'm writing code in Pydroid, an IDE for Android.

Answer (score 1):

Try reading the file as:
df = pd.read_csv(filename,encoding = "ISO-8859-1")

ISO-8859-1 works well with Latin names

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using encoding='utf-8'? like this

```
with open('x.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
Yes, I've already tried to write like that, but it changed nothing.
It prints '+aok-' for every 'é' in a random word.

Comment: Can you try to use print("é") just to see what the console prints out, in case it's an issue related to the IDE you are using

Comment: I can print 'é' and other french caracters, so i don't think that is IDE's problem.